# Searching for a text in LongBlob column from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, blob

I have a mysql database with column name col1 of type LONGBLOB. I want to search for all rows that contain a string called 'false' in the col1. This is the query i am using but i am getting an empty set

```
  select * from Test t where CAST(t.col1 AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) 
   like '%false%';
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Casting a big field before search is not a good idea.

You can add a FULLTEXT index to your table, but you must convert your `longblob` field to longtext or make a field as copy of it, and then:

```
create fulltext index `ilongtext` on Test(col1_copy);
```

You will able to search like:

```
select * from Test where match (col1_copy) against ('+false');
```

It will be more fast